# Why does package installation fail if the setup file isn't named setup.py?

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py

I ran into this when I wanted to split a self-written package into two packages. I added another `setup.py`and gave both new names to keep them apart. However, at that point installing the package does not work.

A minimal example:

```
src
+--test_package
|   +--__init__.py
+--setup_package.py
```

Where `__init__.py` is empty and `setup_package.py` contains basic setup code

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['package',],
      )
```

I create a package with `python setup-package.py sdist --formats=zip` and attempt to install with `pip install ./dist/package-0.1.zip`. This fails because it cannot find `setup.py`. If I rename `setup-package.py` to `setup.py`, and then rebuilt the package, I can install without problems. `SOURCES.txt` does not list `setup.py` as required.

A few other things I tried:
Renaming `setup-package.py` for the installation without rebuilding also produces an error.
Adding an empty `setup.py` and using `setup-package.py` does not work either.

I'm very much a beginner where packaging is concerned, but I didn't see any warning that `setup.py` is absolutly required and has to have that specific name. Checking for this post I can't find any warning like that either, though I haven't done a deep dive. But having two packages in the same directory and wanting to build them both doesn't seem like an extremly out there usage, in which case you want to have two `setup.py` files. Which obviously isn't possibly, so you need to give them different names, but then it won't work.

Why does this happen? Working around the issue isn't too difficult, but it's rather puzzling to me, and I'd like to know why this happens (and how you're intended to do things).

Comment: _pip_ (and other tools) expect a file `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`, but that is another story), so that's just how it is. You could probably somewhat work around that by building and distributing only the _wheels_ instead of the _source distributions_ (_sdist_). Otherwise you could probably write a `setup.py` that takes an extra parameter so that it can build both projects (I think this question has been asked before).

Comment: If it has, then I didn't see it. Working around it isn't a particular issue, just putting them into seperate folders works, as does renaming manually (when you don't have to rebuilt it too often). I'm really more interested why it happens in the first place.

Comment: When a _source distribution_ (`sdist`) is built, a copy of the `setup.py` file is placed in the archive (the distribution). When _pip_ (for example) tries to install, it unpacks the archive and "_executes_" the `setup.py` (it's a bit more complicated than that but it doesn't matter). If there is no `setup.py`, then _pip_ can not build the distribution and can not install it.